# Ruby for statement using undefined variables

Tags: ruby, learn-ruby-the-hard-way

I'm a beginner at programming, and I'm trying to complete Zed Shaw's book for Ruby, and I just cannot understand the last `for` statement of the code.  If the variables `state` and `abbrev` have not been defined, how does the software know where to get values for them?

```
states = {
    'Oregon' => 'OR',
    'Florida' => 'FL',
    'California' => 'CA',
    'New York' => 'NY',
    'Michigan' => 'MI'
}

cities = {
    'CA' => 'San Francisco',
    'MI' => 'Detroit',
    'FL' => 'Jacksonville'
}

for state, abbrev in states
    puts "%s state is abbreviated %s and has city %s" % [
        state, abbrev, cities[abbrev]]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those variables are valid only within the `for` ... `end` iteration. It is similar to block variables such as `x` in a block `{|x| .... x ...}`. The values are assigned to each element of `states`, or, if it does not have a natural sense of an element, then `to_a`, will be applied. In the following, `e` is assigned an element of `states`,

```
for e in states
  ...
end
```

and change each time as it goes through the iteration. Since `states` is a hash, it will be an array of key-value pair like `['Oregon', 'OR']`.

But there is one more complication to that; that is called destructive assignment. When the number of variables and the object does not match during assignment, Ruby tries to distribute them to make much sense as possible. In this case, you have `state` and `abbrev`, which are two variables, to be assigned a single array like `['Oregon', 'OR']`. Ruby decomposes that array, and assigns its elements to each variable:

```
state # => "Oregon"
abbrev # => "OR"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `for`-`in` construct in this case iterates through the `states` Hash; for each key-value pair, `state` is set to the key and `abbrev` is set to the value.  So the first time through, `state` is set to `'Oregon'` and `abbrev` is set to `'OR'`, then `state` is set to `'Florida'` and `abbrev` is set to `'FL'`, and so on through the whole Hash.  This is simply the way the `for`-`in` syntax is defined to work in Ruby.

Comment: Thank you! This makes more sense now, although as a beginner I still find it strange.